# getting "ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the list [green-players" error in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent

This is the code of a 2 player game that I manipulated

```
o play-the-game
  if (any-friends-nearby?) [gain-energy]
  if (any-opponents-nearby?) [fight-opponent]
end

to-report any-friends-nearby?
  report (any? (turtles-on neighbors4) with [breed = [breed] of myself])
end

to-report any-opponents-nearby?
  report (any? (turtles-on neighbors4) with [breed != [breed] of myself])
end


to gain-energy
  set similar-nearby count ( turtles-on neighbors4 )
 with
  [color = [color] of myself]
  set total-nearby count (turtles-on neighbors)
  ;
  ;
  if (similar-nearby >= total-nearby - similar-nearby)
  [set energy energy + 5]
end

to fight-opponent
  let my-breed [breed] of green-players
  let my-color [color] of green-players
  let opponent-breed [breed] of red-players
  ;
  ;;
  ask my-breed
  [check-random-winner]

end

to check-random-winner
  let pick random-float 2
  let winner nobody
  ask turtles
  [if winner = nobody
    [ ifelse size > pick
      [set winner self ]
      [set pick pick - size] ] ]
end

to change-opponent
  ask red-players
  [ set breed green-players
      set color green ]
end
```

Sorry if it's a bit long but when I setup up and then press go "ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the list [green-players...]"

How can I fix this?
Also I'm very new to Netlogo and StackOverflow, apologies if I haven't asked my question properly.

Comment: I posted an answer but know that in code questions you should provide a [mre]: who reads your question should be able to copy your code, paste it on their software without making changes or additions, and be able to reproduce the problem you are describing. In this case, I had to add `turtles-own` variables, the `setup` procedure and the `go` procedure to make it work. In any case this does not mean that you should post your entire code: what you need to aim for is a reduced version of your code, of the minimal size that is needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that you are passing a list (more specifically, a list of breeds) to `ask`, when it comes to `ask my-breed`.

This is because the `my-breed` local variable is determined by

```
let my-breed [breed] of green-players
```

Let's see what we have there:

1. `breed` [is a turtles-own variable](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breedvar): it holds the turtle's breed, and being an agents' variable can be used as a reported in the `of` construct (see below).
2. `of` [is a reporter](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of): it takes a reporter (normally an agents' variable) on its left (in your case: `breed`) and either an agent or an agentset on its right (in your case: `green-players`). What `of` reports (i.e. what it outputs) is...

   - ... a single value if there is an agent on the right.
   - ... a list of values if there is an agentset on the right*.

   *Think about it: if I ask the color of your eyes (you are a single person, i.e. a single agent), you will tell me a single color. But if I ask the color of your friends' eyes (your friends are a group of people, i.e. an agentset), the only way for you to answer my question is to tell me a list of colors.
3. `green-players` [is an agentset](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agentsets): all of the agents whose breed is `green-players` (note that for NetLogo `green-players` is an agentset even if it contains 1 or 0 agents).

From this, we can see that in this case `of` reports a list of breeds, because it reports the breed of every agent that is part of `green-players`, hence it will report the list `[green-players green-players green-players green-players ... ]` which is as long as the number of `green-players` in the model. You can verify this by clicking `setup` and then running `[breed] of green-players` in the Command Center.

This is a list of breeds (which can also be seen as a list of agentsets), which is not an agent or an agentset (which are the only possible targets of `ask`).

((note that the exact same thing happens with `let my-color [color] of green-players` and `let opponent-breed [breed] of red-players`))

So, how do you construct an agentset based on a variable? The most common way to do it is by using `with` ([read here why](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with)).

But how can you fix your code? I don't know because I don't understand what you want to achieve.

I am not sure how you would want to use it in the code you posted, as I'm not even sure you need to use `ask` in `fight-opponent` (let alone `ask` an agentset).
Your `fight-opponent` procedure is such that, apart from the problem we just discussed, the "my-" things (i.e. `my-breed` and `my-color`) always refer to the green players while `opponent-breed` always refers to the red players - even if `fight-opponent` is run by a red player! And also, it is not clear what you want to achieve with the `check-random-winner` procedure and if you want this procedure to be ran by an entire breed. These things make it quite confusing to understand how you could want to fix the `fight-opponent` procedure.

For example: who do you want to run the `check-random-winner` command?

A combination of two things would be beneficial: develop your model one step at a time and make sure that every new little piece of code does exactly what you expect it to do; also, when you ask for how to fix something it is useful that you explain what you want your code to do. By doing these two things I believe it will be a lot easier to answer your questions